# VARBINARY output in MS MGMT Studio different than Powershell/.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm in a bit of a situation with outputting data from a table where the only column I'm selecting is a VARBINARY(MAX) type.

In management studio, when I execute the query, I get back what I expect in the format:

```
0x1FABCDEFG......etc
```

Now, when the same query is executed in powershell, via a simple setup of a SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter and DataSet, the file is eventually output which uses the following command:

```
$dataSet.Tables[0] | Select-Object * | Export-Csv $outputFileName -Force -NoTypeInformation;
```

..it returns a bunch of rows that simply contain:

```
System.Byte[]
```

A byte array isn't what I want, just the same output that's shown when you execute it in SQL Management Studio...

Is there some kind of cast/convert magic I can do in the query (SQL 2005 btw), or do I need to go through the DataSet object and mess around with the data there (which is not ideal for the situation but can be done).

Any help or a pat on the back letting me know that I should just take my whole idea out back and shoot it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this and think it may help. [Microsoft blog Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx) which explains how to do hex to string and vise versa. If you add it to the SQL command it might do the trick

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the link!